# Highcharts change chart type on drop down Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**Scenario:**
I Have a highchart on my intranet page which displays some business stats, I would like to give the user the option of changing the type of graph that is generated. But after reading multiple SO posts, I have had no luck.

*I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557984/highcharts-change-chart-type-using-dropdown-for-multiple-series) post, which granted wasnt marked as answered, but his [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zuXDG/) seems to do what I want*

I grabbed this code from that solution:

```
$("#chartType").change(function() {
    var type = this.value;
    if(type !== '0') {
        $(chart.series).each(function(){
            this.update({
                type: type 
            }, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
    }
});
```

The problem I seem to be having is that I build my graph differently to how he has done it and I cant seem to understand what he is doing (I am not that great at Jquery, and even worse off with Highcharts stuff)

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z2x816bf/1/) of my attempt and the furthest I have been able to get. I am not sure why it doesnt `redraw` my graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a very small problem, actually the cdhleads (chart reference) you are using inside your change function doesn't get the chart reference because it's out of its scope. so you need to get the chart reference first as:

```
var cdhleads = $('#CDHLeads').highcharts();
```

**[See your working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2x816bf/2/)**

Comment: Oh Man!! Thank you so much! Literally been stuck on this the whole morning.

Comment: No worries, also mark the answer correct if it answered your question (:

Comment: Will do, as soon as 3minutes have gone by :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call a function drawChart() (on  onchange event) which actually re-Initiates the chart:

```
function drawChart() {

  var options = {

          chart: {

              type: $("#filter").find("select[name=chartType]").val()

          }

    // ... Rest of the options

  };

  $('#chart').highcharts(options);

}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you mate, already used the answer before your one :) but +1